Animating a 2D character to speak
I have a 2D character created in the following formats .png and .ai. I would like to animate this character to speak some script, but I can't find any tool that can do it. They all support characters created in their service etc.
Do you know any tool for this case?

Adobe Character Animator can do this.  The paid version lets you add your own images, define them as limbs, keyframes for mouth etc, and animate based on keyframes or by using your webcam. It's pretty good.
https://www.adobe.com/products/character-animator.html
It's included as part of the Adobe creative suite I think.
If you're confident with After Effects, you could also look at Duik. It's a free but very complicated & powerful way to animate 2D rigs, using bones and 'inverse kinematics'
Example here for lip syncing using Duik:



